# Show convergence of sets

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, limits-and-convergence

Consider these sets
$$
A\equiv \bigcap_{\delta>0} \liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty} \{x \in X: d(p_n, [\ell(x), u(x)])\leq \delta\}
$$
$$
C_n(L_n)\equiv \{x \in X: d(p_n, [\ell(x), u(x)])\leq L_n\}
$$
where:

- $A$ is non-empty.
- $(p_n)_n$   is a sequence of  reals taking values in $[0,1]$.
- $\ell(\cdot)$ and $u(\cdot)$ are real  function taking values in $[0,1]$.
- $d\big(p_n,  [\ell(x), u(x) ] \big):= \inf \big\{|p_n - y| : y \in [\ell(x), u(x) ] \big\}$.
- $L_n$ is a sequence of strictly positive reals converging to zero as $n$ goes to infinity.

---

Does $d_H(A, C_n(L_n))$ go to zero, where
$$
d_H(A, B)\equiv \max\{\sup_{x\in B}d(x,A), \sup_{x\in A}d(x, B)\},
$$
is the Hausdorff distance?

Comment: I guess you wanted $\cup$ instead of $\cap$ everywhere.

Comment: This about this a bit more.

Comment: I wanted to say: Think about this a bit more. Sorry for for the typo.

Comment: The latter inequality in your second display is not true in general.

Comment: The equality $\bigcap_{0<\delta\leq L}  \{x \in X: d(p_n, [\ell(x), u(x)])\leq \delta\}=\{x \in X: d(p_n, [\ell(x), u(x)])\leq L\}$ is not true in general.

Comment: It will be true if $\cap$ is replaced by $\cup$, or if $L$ on the right-hand side is replaced by $0$.

Comment: According to [these guidlelines](https://mathoverflow.net/help/how-to-answer), users should "avoid trying to answer questions which [...] request answers to multiple questions". Therefore, I suggest that the very non-specific "Can we say something" question be removed, leaving only the question "does this distance go to zero?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand\de\delta$The answer is no. In fact, $d_H(A,C_n(L_n))$ can be however large or even infinite for all $n$.

Indeed, e.g. suppose that $X=[-1,a)$ for some $a\in(0,\infty]$ endowed with the standard metric $|\cdot-\cdot|$, $\ell(x)=u(x)=-x$ for $x\in[-1,0]$, $\ell(x)=u(x)=0$ for $x\in[0,a)$. Let $(L_n)$ be any positive sequence converging to $0$, and let $p_n=2L_n$ eventually (that is, for all large enough $n$). Then $A\supseteq[0,a)$ and $C_n(L_n)=[-3L_n,-L_n]$ eventually, so that eventually
$$d_H(A,C_n(L_n))\ge|(a-L_n)-(-L_n)|=a$$
if $a<\infty$, and $d_H(A,C_n(L_n))=\infty$ if $a=\infty$.

---

**Details:** Let $A_n(\de):=\{x\in X\colon d(p_n,[\ell(x),u(x)])\le\de\}$ and $A(\de):=\liminf_{n\to\infty}A_n(\de)$, so that $A=\bigcap_{\de>0}A(\de)$.

For each $\de>0$, eventually $A_n(\de)\supseteq[0,a)$, so that $A(\de)\supseteq[0,a)$ for all $\de>0$ and hence $A\supseteq[0,a)$, as was claimed.

Also, $C_n(L_n)=A_n(L_n)=\{x\in[-1,0]\colon |p_n-(-x)|\le L_n\}=[-3L_n,-L_n]$ eventually, as was claimed, too.

Comment: Thanks. Is your example showing that there is no $L_n$ that makes the claim true?

Comment: @Star : Essentially, this example shows that, for any positive sequence $(L_n)$ converging to $0$, we can construct $X,\ell,u,(p_n)$ with $d_H(A,C_n(L_n))$ however large or even infinite for all $n$. I believe that all this pursuit, without serious structural restrictions on $\ell$ and $u$ (such as a seriously strong version of injectivity) is, unfortunately, fruitless.

Comment: But it seems that you have picked a specific $L_n$?

Comment: @Star : I did that in order for the counterexample to be simple and specific. However, the counterexample can be easily modified for any positive sequence $(L_n)$ converging to $0$ -- by then letting $p_n:=2L_n$, say. There are a huge number of degrees of freedom in constructing a counterexample under your conditions.

Comment: If it is not a huge work, could you edit your answer along those lines?

Comment: @Star : Since your question has already been fully answered (along with a number of extra comments of mine), I will do this modification (which, I believe, does not change anything of essence) if this is the last additional request.

Comment: Yes, please, thanks

Comment: @Star : This is now done.

Comment: @Star : Do you have a further response to this answer?

Comment: Thanks. I think I'm OK with that. Am I right to say that if $L_n\equiv L>0$, then the distance goes to zero?

Comment: "the distance"? What distance?

Comment: The Hausdorff distance, sorry.

Comment: @Star : No, I don' t think so. You actually seem to go in the wrong direction with the constant $L$. Anyhow, didn't we [agree](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/467446/show-convergence-of-sets/467706?noredirect=1#comment1214281_467706) that, as your question had already been fully answered (along with a number of extra comments of mine), your last additional request was at Mar 25 at 18:30? Also, let me repeat: "I believe that all this pursuit, without serious structural restrictions on $\ell$ and $u$ (such as a seriously strong version of injectivity) is, unfortunately, fruitless. "

Comment: Previous comment continued: Your additional requests keep ignoring that and concern things that cannot possibly make a substantial difference.

Comment: there is no rule on how many questions I can ask. You are free not to reply.

Comment: Also, it must be that for $L_n=L>0$, $C_n(L)$ tends to a superset of $A$... This is by definition.